# Quirky JS Code In Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, css

On the site http://www.thestartupprogram.com/ an odd JS script is setting the .header4 height to 57px. For the life of me I can't find the file that's causing this; I want to remove it. It's probably easy to solve, but I'm not thinking straight. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The JS is included inline on the index page.

Line 400:

```
var headheight = (jQuery(".logo").outerHeight());
```

Line 405:

```
jQuery(".header4").height(headheight)
```